# Hibernate code..some confusion

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Consultants consultants = new Consultants();  // 1
        consultants.setUsername("Rahul");             // 2     
        consultants.setPass("rahul");                 // 3
        session.save(consultants);                     
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

see, in above code except 1,2 and 3 statement all code remains same for each method. Is there any best way to re-write above code each time i.e way to us same code again and again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about what kind of repetition are you complaining about, but you can create a "generic" method to save any mapped entity:

```
public void save(Object entity) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(entity);                     
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

And then use this method when you want to save a Consultant:

```
    Consultants consultants = new Consultants();
    consultants.setUsername("Rahul");
    consultants.setPass("rahul");

    save(consultants);
```

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, very definitely. What you've identified is an opportunity for applying the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). See, for example, Spring's [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html). Even if you don't want to use Spring--if you're using Hibernate, you should probably manage it with Spring anyway--you can take a [look at the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.java.html) to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

By mean all code you mean the transaction handling and the roll back mechanism?
I real word application generally Transaction are being regarded as another layer and we generally call this as separation of concern.

If you are using Spring, all you have to do is to move your transaction handling outside of the java code using AOP.
Without Spring there are other way to handle transaction management

here is the link to spring documentation for transaction management
[transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html)

Answer (score 0):

> transaction = session.beginTransaction();
>           session.save(entity);
>           transaction.commit();

To avoid the above repetition in all persistence related method you have to go through `HibernateTemplate or JpaTemplate` Which handle the above repetition for us. And for save operation you have to just call `save(object)` it will save your data into the persistence you don't have to worry about the implementation of it.